# PDO is giving weird results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm gettng a weird error from PDO and it doesn't make sense. I am trying the following code but even if I change the code I get the exact same error that doesn't reflect any of the changes.

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT database, gpsthr from ccprefs where fleetnumber=?");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, (int) $smpfleet, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Here's the error message:

**"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' gpsthr from ccprefs where fleetnumber= ?' at line 1"**

If I change the code to this I still get the same error.

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT database, gpsthr from ccprefs where fleetnumber= :fleet");
    $stmt->bindValue(':fleet', (int) $smpfleet, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: `database` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Wrap it in backticks or change it.

Comment: that was dumb. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATABASE` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) and as such you have to [quote](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html) it.